# LINQ error on join: "CS1061 'Guid' doesn't contain a definition for <column name>

Tags: linq, linqpad

I'm learning LINQ, using LINQPAD for testing, and have run into an error with JOINing that I cannot explain.  I've searched this forum and the closest accepted answer I can find is that the keys I'm joining on aren't of the same data type, but I can absolutely guarantee that they are (they're both GUIDs).

Here is the code that fails, though online references and tutorials tell me that I am writing this correctly:

```
var Table1 = (from fis in FinancialInstitutionExaminers
              select fis.InvitedByID).Distinct();

var Table2 = (from c in Contacts
              select new {c.ID, c.FirstName, c.LastName });



var JoinedTables2 = Table1.Join(Table2,
                                k1 => k1.InvitedByID,  // This causes failure
                                k2 => k2.ID,
                                (k1, k2) => 
                                        new {
                                                //ConID = k1.InvitedByID,
                                                ConFirstName = k2.FirstName,
                                                ConLastName = k2.LastName
                                            });                             
JoinedTables2.Dump();
```

The problem is with the line **k1 => k1.InvitedByID**.  When I specify the column "**InvitedByID**," I get the error "CS1061 'Guid' doesn't contain a definition for 'InvitedByID'.

InvitedByID **does** exist in my data source, and it is the same type as the column I am joining on (ID, specified by k2=> k2.ID in my join).  Both columns are GUIDs.

Here is what throws me.  If I modify the code as below, removing InvitedBy from k1 => k1.InvitedBy, the code works.  This baffles me.  I don't understand (1) why I can't explicitly use the column name in the join and (2) how the code can possibly **work** without it (I can see how LINQ can infer it should join on the only column selected for Table1, but again, if it has no problem with the data type of that column, why can't I name it explicitly?)

This works:

```
var Table1 = (from fis in FinancialInstitutionExaminers
              select fis.InvitedByID).Distinct();

var Table2 = (from c in Contacts
              select new {c.ID, c.FirstName, c.LastName });



var JoinedTables2 = Table1.Join(Table2,
                                k1 => k1,   // Note I removed InvitedBy
                                k2 => k2.ID,
                                (k1, k2) => 
                                        new {
                                                //ConID = k1.InvitedByID,
                                                ConFirstName = k2.FirstName,
                                                ConLastName = k2.LastName
                                            });                             
JoinedTables2.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are projecting (using `select`) incorrectly. It seems that you are trying to access the property `InvitedByID` of an object of whatever type `T` in`IEnumerable<T> FinancialInstitutionExaminers` (fill in this `T` with whatever type you use since I cannot see that part of your code). That property returns a `GUID`. So, Table1 is of Type `IEnumerable<GUID>`, and and not of the type `IEnumerable<T>`. While `var` can be useful, its overuse often leads to errors like these.

Try :

```
var Table1 = FinancialInstitutionExaminers.Distinct();

var Table2 = (from c in Contacts
          select new {c.ID, c.FirstName, c.LastName });



var JoinedTables2 = Table1.Join(Table2,
                            k1 => k1.InvitedByID, 
                            k2 => k2.ID,
                            (k1, k2) => 
                                    new {
                                            ConID = k1.InvitedByID,
                                            ConFirstName = k2.FirstName,
                                            ConLastName = k2.LastName
                                        });                             
JoinedTables2.Dump();
```

Comment: Perfect solution kotval, and I agree on the overuse of "var".  Your explanation of how it leads to the error is a good learning point.  It was my practice for years to avoid "var" at all costs, but I'm in a shop now that relies on it heavily, and the tutorials I'm learning from use it, so I fell into that trap.  Hopefully other newbies such as I who fall into this trap will see your answer and sgmoore's clarification and end up with a better understanding and clearer code because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Kotval's answer is perfectly correct, but you would also write the first part like

```
var Table1 = (from fis in FinancialInstitutionExaminers
           select new { fis.InvitedByID } ).Distinct();
```

The difference is when you use `k1 =>`, k1 will be an object which contains a Guid called InvitedByID and hence you can say `k1 => k1.InvitedByID` whereas in your code k1 is the Guid and you have to say `k1 => k1`.

Comment: Wonderful clarification sgmoore.  I really like your rewriting of the first part because I can explicitly see the InvitedBy column in the select.  IMHO that's clearer code.  I wish I could mark two answers as accepted :-(